# How to delete Duplicates on a Text

Tags: php, html, regex, notepad++, duplicates

I want a tool or how to use notepad++ or any other tools to delete both duplicates lines in a text, 
all tools I found delete only the duplicate line and leaves the original

```
I want to delete them both , like that:

line1
line2
line2
line3

i want the result be :

line1
line3
```

Comment: Some questions: why the abuse of tags? What have you tried? Are the lines that should be removed consecutive? Please be precise and show your attempts. We can't read your mind.

Comment: @HamZa hey man the lines are not consecutive, I tried some online tools that remove duplicates...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551526/removing-duplicate-lines-with-random-text-behind-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940950/notepad-check-for-duplicate-lines-complex which ask similar questions. Their answers, with minor changes, may do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Find what: `^(.+)\R([\s\S]+)\R\1`
Replace with: `Nothing`

Make sure you've selected `Regular expression` and NOT `Dot matches newline`
Click on `Replace all` as many times as necessary.

**Edit:**
Depending on your version of npp, you could use instead:

Find what: `^(.+)[\r\n]+([\s\S]+)[\r\n]+\1`
Replace with: `Nothing`

Comment: @M42 thank you but when doing these steps in notepad++ i got 0 occurences.. i never worked with regex, so do I have to change something in that code '^(.+)\R([\s\S]+)\R\1'